# two grooves in wheel rim

Tags: wheels, repair, rims, rim-brake

Schwinn midtown bicycle, when replacing brakes I see the wheel has many grooves as shown in picture. I do not remember how it was before. Is this condition normal for the wheel rim?

Photo of the old rim and the old brakepad:
[image]
[image]

Two images of the new rim:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think it might be easier to interpret the first photo if the rim (or at least a section of it) was clean

Comment: Does a Schwinn branded rim have wear indicators when new?  I can't find info either way with a quick search.   Does your other wheel have the same marks?

Comment: Yes both wheels have the same marks.

Comment: @PaulH thanks! clearer image added

Comment: looks like wear indicators to me. it's when you _can't_ see them that you should worry

Comment: @PaulH thank you for your reply. Just added one more photo. Could you please check?

Comment: yeah same take. do they go all the way around the rim at a constant radius?

Comment: @PaulH yes this is the same pattern around all rim on both sides of both wheels

Comment: Brake pad seems very worn out. pay attention to the wear line: 
https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/dKuOvxSnpsDIE2R6.medium

Comment: In my experience causing any deep grooves would only be possible to cause with extremely worn out brake pads, and you'd definitely notice that by a nasty grinding noise while braking.

Comment: Unrelated anecdote: I have lost a (cheap) bike because the rim broke exactly along the wear marks :/

Answer (score 17):

These are wear indicators.

After years of braking, the surface of the rim will grind down to a point that these grooves will no longer be discernable. At that point, you should replace the rim.

Comment: And while theyre doing it, they represent greater contact patch area for the brake blocks once the blocks have a ridge worn into them :)

Comment: The groves are far too regular to stem from wear. They were clearly machined into the rim for a purpose, either to break a film of water on the rim or as wear indicator, maybe for both purposes.

Comment: @Carel yes. that sums up my answer